# Define rule to make members private if possible

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-code, resharper, tslint

So I'm in the process of building a ruleset to enforce in our team to finally get the codebase consistent.

For C# I have Rehsarper's

```
<s:String x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/Highlighting/InspectionSeverities/=MemberCanBePrivate_002EGlobal/@EntryIndexedValue">ERROR</s:String>
```

rule which perfectly tells everyone to make their stuff private or protected if possible.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to apply to Typescript.

I'd prefer a rule that can be stored in the .editorconfig (universal) or .DotSettings (Resharper) file, but I will be grateful for any hints of how to define this rule.

We have VS2017 (hopefully 2019 soon), Resharper, ts-lint, and probably StyleCop if we need it.

Edit: Also since my Google-Fu failed, I'll gladly take any hints on where to research these rules. MSDN has a nice page, but those rules apply to C#/VB only or aren't 'smart' enough for many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a rule does not exist. https://palantir.github.io/tslint

You could request it on TSLint's GitHub repository, https://github.com/palantir/tslint/, but we should note that [TSLint is being deprecated soon](https://medium.com/palantir/tslint-in-2019-1a144c2317a9) so it's unlikely to be created now.

Comment: Hey nice to see they're being unified. Guess we can wait a bit more.